# How get the all list of all my Visits ID using fingerprintjs API

Tags: javascript, mysql, fingerprintjs2

**I want to count all visits on my site without repeating by device so I'm using this api**

````
  // Initialize the agent at application startup.
  const fpPromise = import('https://fpcdn.io/v3/ public key')
    .then(FingerprintJS => FingerprintJS.load());

  // Get the visitor identifier when you need it.
  fpPromise
    .then(fp => fp.get({ linkedId: 'your-linked-id', tag: { yourTag: 123456 }}))
    .then(result => console.log(result.visitorId));
</script>``` 

>I wanna save in my sql system this adress  how can i do that?
````

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by `adress`?

From the given context I assume you could use [webhooks](https://dev.fingerprintjs.com/docs/webhooks) or [Server API](https://dev.fingerprintjs.com/docs/server-api) on your backend to persist desired data.

Comment: i mean adress that site give to me